# CMake: how do i depend on output from a custom target?

Tags: cmake

A traditional Make process that I cannot modify produces a target on which I must do some post-processing.

I use `add_custom_target` to force the Makefile to always run.
I use `add_custom_command` for my post-processing steps.

The problem is that `add_custom_target` cannot produce an output as far as CMake is concerned. So, how do I setup a dependency for the post-processing steps? I don't want to run these steps unless the external Make actually updated its target.

The `add_custom_command` cannot use the name of the `add_custom_target` as a `DEPENDS`. I tried this and it assumes that the `add_custom_target` name is just a file and cannot find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the add_custom_command call depend on a **file** that changes when "the external make actually updated its target." The custom command will only run if one of its DEPENDS is newer than its OUTPUT.

The DEPENDS for CMake add_custom_command calls work best with older versions of CMake when they are full path file name references. More recent versions of CMake should work with file name or CMake target name references.