# Reusing custom makefile for static library with cmake

Tags: linux, cmake

I guess this would be a generic question on including libraries with existing makefiles within cmake; but here's my context -

I'm trying to include `scintilla` in another CMake project, and I have the following problem:

On Linux, scintilla has a makefile in (say) the `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scintilla/gtk` directory; if you run `make` in that directory (as usual), you get a `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scintilla/bin/scintilla.a` file - which (I guess) is the static library.

Now, if I'd try to use cmake's `ADD_LIBRARY`, I'd have to manually specify the sources of scintilla within cmake - and I'd rather not mess with that, given I already have a makefile. So, I'd rather call the usual scintilla `make` - and then instruct CMAKE to somehow refer to the resulting `scintilla.a`. (*I guess that this then would **not** ensure cross-platform compatibility - but note that currently cross-platform is not an issue for me; I'd just like to build scintilla as part of this project that already uses cmake, only within Linux*)

So, I've tried a bit with this:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
  OUTPUT scintilla.a
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scintilla/gtk
  COMMENT "Original scintilla makefile target" )
```

... but then, add_custom_command adds a "*target with no output*"; so I'm trying several approach to build upon that, all of which fail (errors given as comment):

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(scintilla STATIC DEPENDS scintilla.a) # Target "scintilla" of type UTILITY may not be linked into another target.

ADD_LIBRARY(scintilla STATIC DEPENDS scintilla.a) # Cannot find source file "DEPENDS".

ADD_LIBRARY(scintilla STATIC) # You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library scintilla without any source files.
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(scintilla scintilla.a)
```

I'm obviously quote a noob with cmake - so, is it possible at all to have `cmake` run a pre-existing makefile, and "capture" its output library file, such that other components of the cmake project can link against it?

Many thanks for any answers,
Cheers!

EDIT: possible duplicate: [CMake: how do i depend on output from a custom target? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066811/cmake-how-do-i-depend-on-output-from-a-custom-target) - however, here the breakage seems to be due to the need to specifically have a *library* that the rest of the cmake project would recognize...

- Another related: [cmake - adding a custom command with the file name as a target - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278444/adding-a-custom-command-with-the-file-name-as-a-target); however, it specifically builds an executable from source files (which I wanted to avoid)..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also use imported targets and a custom target like this:

```
# set the output destination
set(SCINTILLA_LIBRARY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scintilla/gtk/scintilla.a)
# create a custom target called build_scintilla that is part of ALL
# and will run each time you type make 
add_custom_target(build_scintilla ALL 
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scintilla/gtk
                   COMMENT "Original scintilla makefile target")

# now create an imported static target
add_library(scintilla STATIC IMPORTED)
# Import target "scintilla" for configuration ""
set_property(TARGET scintilla APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS NOCONFIG)
set_target_properties(scintilla PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_NOCONFIG "${SCINTILLA_LIBRARY}")

# now you can use scintilla as if it were a regular cmake built target in your project
add_dependencies(scintilla build_scintilla)

add_executable(foo foo.c)
target_link_libraries(foo scintilla)

# note, this will only work on linux/unix platforms, also it does building
# in the source tree which is also sort of bad style and keeps out of source 
# builds from working.
```

Comment: Many thanks for that @Bill Hoffman - looks good; didn't know about imported targets!! Btw, to format code, select what is to be your code snippet, and press Ctrl-K in the StackOverflow editor (or just make sure there are four spaces at start) - I tried editing your post, but I don't have edit privileges, so I'm not sure if it will show.. Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: this produces "add_dependencies Adding dependency to non-existent target: scintilla" on CMake 2.8.2

Comment: Not sure why, but it didn't work for me with ninja generator, had to use make. CMake 2.8.12.

Comment: However, ninja did create the target `build_scintilla`, so I could use ninja like this: `ninja build_scintilla; ninja`. Otherwise it complains "scintilla/gtk/scintilla.a missing and no known rule to make it"

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I have it somewhat; basically, in the CMakeLists.txt that build scintilla, I used this only:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(
  scintilla.a ALL
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scintilla/gtk
  COMMENT "Original scintilla makefile target" )
```

... and then, the slightly more complicated part, was to find the correct cmake file elsewhere in the project, where the `${PROJECT_NAME}` was defined - so as to add a dependency:

```
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(${PROJECT_NAME} scintilla.a)
```

... and finally, the library needs to be linked.

Note that in the commands heretofore, the `scintilla.a` is merely a name/label/identifier/string (*so it could be anything else, like `scintilla--a` or something*); but for linking - the full path to the actual `` `scintilla.a `` file is needed (which in this project ends up in a variable `${SCINTILLA_LIBRARY}`). In this project, the linking basically occurs through a form of a

```
list(APPEND PROJ_LIBRARIES ${SCINTILLA_LIBRARY} )
```

... and I don't really know how cmake handles the actual linking afterwards (but it seems to work)

For consistency, I tried to use `${SCINTILLA_LIBRARY}` instead of `scintilla.a` as identifier in the ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET, but got error: "*Target names may not contain a slash.  Use ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND to generate files*". So probably this could be solved smarter/more correct with ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND - however, I read that it "*[defines a new command that can be executed during the build process. The outputs named should be listed as source files in the target for which they are to be generated.](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command%3aadd_custom_command)*"... And by now I'm totally confused so as to what is a file, what is a label, and what is a target - so I think I'll leave at this (and not fix it if it ain't broken :) )

Well, it'd still be nice to know a more correct way to do this eventually,
Cheers!