# add_dependencies transitivity with add_subdirectory

Tags: makefile, cmake

I'm trying to follow the approach taken [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876753/reusing-custom-makefile-for-static-library-with-cmake) to call an existing Makefile (that builds a static library) from within CMake.

My situation looks as follows

- Static library built with a Makefile in directory `project/makefile_lib`
- Another library (`cmake_lib`) built with CMake that depends on `makefile_lib` in directory `project`
- Executable that uses `cmake_lib` also in directory `project`

My `CMakeLists.txt` in `project` looks as follows.

```
project(cmake_makefile)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

add_subdirectory(makefile_lib)

add_library(cmake_lib cmake_lib.c)

target_include_directories(cmake_lib
    PRIVATE makefile_lib
)

target_link_libraries(cmake_lib makefile_lib)

add_executable(main main.c)

target_link_libraries(main cmake_lib)
```

And the `CMakeLists.txt` in `project/makefile_lib`

```
add_custom_target(build_makefile_lib
    ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMENT "makefile_lib makefile"
)

add_library(makefile_lib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(makefile_lib
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libmakefile_lib.a
)

add_dependencies(makefile_lib build_makefile_lib)
```

According to the `add_dependencies` documentation:

> Dependencies added to an IMPORTED target are followed transitively in its place since the target itself does not build.

From within the `project` directory I invoke

```
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ..
make
```

But the Makefile in `project/makefile_lib` is never invoked and the build fails with `cannot find -lmakefile-lib`.

Interestingly, this approach works if I move the content of `project/makefile_lib` into `project` and replace the `add_subdirectory` command in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` with the content of `project/makefile_lib/CMakeLists.txt`.

Why is the `add_dependencies` command in this case seemingly not followed transitively?

Comment: The difference is, that when your code is part of the root `CMakeLists.txt` that `WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` points to your root `project` directory. Otherwise it points to `project/makefile_lib`. Are you sure your `makefile` is in the sub-directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the `add_library` command. From the documentation

> The target name has scope in the directory in which it is created and
>   below, but the GLOBAL option extends visibility.

So the solution was to add the `GLOBAL` option to the `add_library` command in the `project/makefile_lib/CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_custom_target(build_makefile_lib
    ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMENT "makefile_lib makefile"
)

add_library(makefile_lib STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(makefile_lib
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libmakefile_lib.a
)

add_dependencies(makefile_lib build_makefile_lib)
```

---

Edit: Note that this does not work for CMake versions <= 2.8.7 where the `GLOBAL` flag does not yet exist. See [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-March/049575.html) for a possible workaround.