# Custom target that works in subdirectories CMake

Tags: linux, cmake

I am working with cmake as my building platform and am now looking for a way to make a custom target work in subdirectories. What I would like to achieve is to have a target, which generates coverage for us, that works at each subdirectory level

The structure:

```
root
root/CMakeLists.txt (Coverage Target Declaration)
root/Module1/
root/Module2/
root/Module3/
```

So if I go into root I can call `make Coverage`, however if I do this in one of the module folders, it says `` make: *** No rule to make target `coverage'.  Stop. ``.
Is it possible to modify the root CMakeLists.txt file in such a way, that this particular target/command can be executed in each of the sub directories. So similar behaviour as the `make test`.

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does not work, it is a known issue but nowhere properly documented. The question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/33500833/2799037