# CMake custom target with same name as subdirectory not being built

Tags: cmake, gnu-make

I have a subdirectory `foo/` which I want to build

**`CMakeLists.txt:`**

```
add_subdirectory(foo)
```

Inside `foo/` I have a number of targets I want to build, and I want to *"group"* them under a single phony target, also called `foo`.

**`foo/CMakeLists.txt:`**

```
add_custom_target(foo ALL)

add_library   (foo_lib ...)
add_executable(foo_bin ...)
add_executable(foo_tests ...)

add_dependencies(foo foo_lib)
add_dependencies(foo foo_bin)
add_dependencies(foo foo_test)
```

This will allow me to build all these related targets by typing `make foo`

This works fine, **except when I am in the directory above `foo/`**

`make foo` in the directory in which `foo` subdirectory exists does nothing.

I believe this is because `make` considers `foo` a target that is not out of date, since the directory exists. The fix is to mark it as a `PHONY` target.

According to the CMake documentation on [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html), the target will **always** be considered out-of-date (ie: in `make` parlance, it will be a `PHONY` target).

**Question:**

Why is my `foo` custom target not being built inside the directory containing the `foo` subdirectory?

Comment: Having a target with the same name as the directory is asking for trouble. Does it work for a different target name?

Comment: As to my knowledge CMake does not generate `PHONY` targets for the subdirectories. They are all on root level. `make help` should list what you can call. Have you considered to add it as an external project?

Comment: @usr1234567 yes, it does work for other targets. This almost certainly is because of the directory with the same name. When you say it's asking for trouble, I can't help but imagine a lot of people have a subdirectory with the same name as an app they're creating, so the target matches the directory name? Ie, this must be a situation which happens a lot?

Comment: In my experience, the only "legal" place where to launch the build from is the `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`, where you generate the folder. Launching `make` from any other place it's "undefined behaviour". If I find the documentation, I'll post a proper answer.

Comment: BTW, what happens if you rename your directory `foo2` and of course use instead `add_subdirectory(foo2)`? (Keeping unchanged the `foo` target)

Comment: @Antonio changing the dir name works. That's not a suitable solution though (for my use case). I can't believe cmake forces you to build all or nothing. The fact that makefiles exist throughout the build tree makes me think that building in a sub tree is by design, and hence, this is a bug rather than undefined behavior.

Comment: I didn't mean you have to build all or nothing, but that from the main directory you have to specify the target in the command line. Would it be an option to use [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) to build? About the modularity, at least for ninja the `build.ninja` file exists only in the main build directory. (BTW, this is a very interesting problem) P.S. Please specify the cmake version.

Comment: CMake + Ninja can only build targets from the ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}, IIRC.

Comment: I once raised [an issue](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15614) in CMake's bug tracker with a [related problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719275/add-custom-command-is-not-generating-a-target) and got the following reply: "CMake is not intended to produce specific content in a Makefile. Top-level target names created by add_custom_target are always logical (i.e. phony) names. It is simply not allowed to have a file of the same name."

Comment: @usr1234567 Yep, I confirm. But you can specify any target in the command line, and the directory with the same name of the target shouldn't be a problem. All my subdirectory CMakeLists.txt files begin with `get_filename_component(targetname "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" NAME)`